# slack api invalid auth error

Tags: python, api, slack-api

I was using the slack python api to build a chatbot but while calling the api I am getting an invalid_auth error in the user.list. The token I am using is the Bot User OAuth Token provided by slack.

```
import slackclient

ADAM_SLACK_NAME = os.environ.get('ADAM_SLACK_NAME')
ADAM_SLACK_TOKEN = os.environ.get('ADAM_SLACK_TOKEN')

adam_slack_client = slackclient.SlackClient(ADAM_SLACK_TOKEN)

print(ADAM_SLACK_NAME)
print(ADAM_SLACK_TOKEN)

is_ok = adam_slack_client.api_call("users.list").get('ok')
print(is_ok)
```

The output I am getting from `is_ok` is `False`. Here is the result of the API call to `users.list`:

```
{'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_auth', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '55', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 31 Jul 2018 16:22:03 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Slack-Req-Id': '9b0519c0-d3b9-4da6-9175-9346a08deed9', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Slack-Backend': 'h', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Via': 'haproxy-www-surh', 'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 66e5950d2a2f44a694f4d9d434e9a3c9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'ZWMCmqhdO8pMsbWXbnL63QppUbFSvzodLtTyjQ-4cB35107QqSowZQ=='}}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: There seems to be no error in the way you call the API. I can only guess that you used an invalid token. To see that, you could use another API method, like `api.test`, see https://python-slackclient.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/#basic-api-methods.

Comment: You should confirm if `os.environ.get('ADAM_SLACK_TOKEN')` is set

Comment: Yes the environment variable is set. I checked it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using nodeJS for making `oauth.access` call and I got this error. Turned out i missed `encodeURIComponent` for `SLACK_REDIRECT_URI`. Hope that helps someone.